# Change Default version of PHP that is called on the command line

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

is there a way to change the default version of PHP that is called on the command line?

I am trying to install Laravel using composer the problem is composer is calling php (which is version 4.4) when it needs to call php5.4, i have changed the binary in the header from `#!/usr/bin/env php` to `#!/usr/bin/env php5.4` but this throws an error!

here is my php set-up

```
php: /usr/bin/php /usr/bin/php5.4 /usr/bin/php5.5 /usr/lib/php /usr/lib/php.ini-nourl /usr/lib/php.ini /usr/lib/php5.4 /usr/lib/php5.5 /usr/local/bin/php /usr/local/bin/php5.4 /usr/local/bin/php5.5 /usr/local/lib/php.ini-nourl /usr/include/php /usr/include/php5.4 /usr/include/php5.5 /usr/local/php /usr/share/php
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple options here, but really this is not php specific, this is about basic execution path rules.

- The `#!/usr/bin/env php` header means that when you run `composer` alone it runs it with `php`, so if you manually run it like `php5.4 /path/to/composer` you can bypass that header.
- The other option is to define a symlink in /usr/local/bin/php or something that:

  - points to /usr/bin/php5.4
  - is in a directory that has precedence over /usr/bin inside your PATH environment variable.